# KVO notifications with a custom property getter

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I am trying to listen to the `editable` property on a `UITextView` in iOS. In the header for `UITextView.h`, the `editable` property is defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isEditable) BOOL editable;
```

To listen for the KVO notification, I'm using the addObserver pattern where I pass the keyPath as `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isEditable))`, so that Xcode will warn me if I'm using a selector that isn't defined. Registering for the `isEditable` keypath goes off without a hitch, but then I never receive a notification that the property changes after changing the `editable` property on the text view. I'm registering the observer with:

```
[self.textView addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isEditable))
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                   context:KVOTestingTestsContext];
```

However, if I instead use the keypath `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(editable))`, I *do* get the KVO notification, but Xcode generates a warning that I am using an undeclared selector 'editable'.

I'm wondering if there is a better pattern then that I should use if this breaks down in the case where one should be using the custom getter. Or is this a bug in Xcode / clang?

Comment: I created a sample project [here](https://github.com/streeter/kvotesting) that has [a testcase](https://github.com/streeter/kvotesting/blob/master/KVOTestingTests/KVOTestingTests.m#L83) that shows this failing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be passing the name of the property in the `forKeyPath` parameter of `addObserver`, not the getter or setter:

```
[self.textView addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"editable"
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                   context:KVOTestingTestsContext];
```

There's no need to generate the key path using `NSStringFromSelector` and `@selector`. In fact, when you do so, you potentially run into the problem you're facing...

1. The key path is based off the name of the property, not the getter. The reason for this is that you want KVO to intercept the `setEditable` method. If you pass `@"isEditable"` (no matter how it's generated) to `addObserver`, KVO will try to intercept the setter for a property called `isEditable`, and this property does not exist.
2. You get the notification using your second approach because you end up passing `@"editable"` to `addObserver`, which is what you want to do, but you're doing it by referencing a non-existent method (i.e. `editable`), hence the compiler warning.
3. Since you can't pass the name of the getter or the setter method to `addObserver`, the answer is to just pass the name of the property directly using a string literal (i.e. `@"editable"`).

Here's Apple's programming guide for reference: [Registering for Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)

Comment: +1 esp +1 for "godel". not sure if this has anything to do with your name, but this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel,_Escher,_Bach inspired me to learn about CS.

Comment: @danh That's exactly where it came from, and I agree on the inspiration to study CS! :-)

Comment: The reason why using `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(...))` is considered a good practice is that you get compiler checks for key existence this way. This saves you from many potential hours of wondering why your observers aren't called before realizing that you have a typo in your key path.

Comment: It took me a while to really understand the reason for this problem. As you state, the keypath KVO wants is the `@property` name and while that's usually the same as the getter for a property, it's not necessarily so. Using `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myProperty))`  is a good but slightly hacky trick.

Comment: Also, the place most people probably get the `@selector` trick from is NSHipster's KVO page which uses a custom getter name as the example: `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isFinished))`